# Java check if the string is an anagram of another string O ( log n )

Tags: java, algorithm

So I've recently been researching all there is to do with run-time complexity of algorithms and wanting to learn how to alter them to improve efficiency for when the scale of n is increased, so essentially my aim is to learn how to make things O (log n). Thought to myself, I know of a good little project I could do this hour and thats create an anagram checker.

I rummaged through a few SO posts and saw someone commented it could be made log n if you assigned every letter in the alphabet to a numeric thus:

```
final Map<Character, Integer> map;
        String str = "hello";
        String check = "olleh";

        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put('a', 2);
        map.put('b', 3);
        map.put('c', 4);
        map.put('d', 7);
        map.put('e', 11);
        map.put('f', 13);
        map.put('g', 17);
        map.put('h', 19);
        map.put('i', 23);
        map.put('j', 29);
        map.put('k', 31);
        map.put('l', 37);
        map.put('m', 41);
        map.put('n', 43);
        map.put('o', 47);
        map.put('p', 53);
        map.put('q', 59);
        map.put('r', 61);
        map.put('s', 67);
        map.put('t', 71);
        map.put('u', 73);
        map.put('v', 79);
        map.put('w', 83);
        map.put('x', 89);
        map.put('y', 97);
        map.put('z', 101);
```

Then I created the method:

```
 public static boolean isAnagram(String s, String check,Map<Character, Integer> map) {
        int stringTotal = 0;
        int checkTotal = 0;
        for(char ch: s.toCharArray()){
            int i = map.get(ch);
            stringTotal += ch;
        }
        for(char ch: check.toCharArray()){
            int i = map.get(ch);
            checkTotal +=ch;
        }
        if (stringTotal == checkTotal){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I believe that this method is O(n^2) because it has two independent loops, I cannot think of the logic behind creating this to a O(log n) method.

Any pointers would be great

Comment: FYI two independent loops doesn't mean O(N^2). Think about it... you're going through an array of length N two times (2N). A quick check upfront to make sure you don't spend time in an expensive-ish operation would be to make sure the lengths of the strings are equal prior to your logic.

Comment: oh yeah of course @Tgsmith61591 thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Please check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/42058276/379173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be `O(2n)`: one loop of `n` after another. You'd get `O(n^2)` if you *nest* a loop of `n` within a loop of `n`,
like so:

```
int count = 0;
for ( int x = 0; x < n; x++ )
     for ( int y = 0; y < n; y++ )
         count++;
```

Here, `count` will be `n*n` or n<sup>2</sup>.

In the code you pasted, there are two loops:

```
int count = 0;
for ( int x = 0; x < n; x++ )
    count++;
for ( int y = 0; y < n; y++ )
    count++;
```

Here, `count` is `n+n` or 2n.

There's no way to make a `O(log n)` function out of this, because you will always need to check all `n` values (all letters).

For example, let's say that we calculated the exact [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of the function to be `log(n)` (note that this is different from the *order* `O(log n)` which does away with coefficients and lower order terms). 
Now, if `n = 10`; then `log(n) = 2.3` (approximately), and you can't be sure a ten letter word is an anagram of another 10 letter word if you only look at 2.3 letters.

Comment: I'd get rid of the last sentence, beginning "For example". If an algorithm has time complexity `O(log n)` there could be a large constant of proportionality. It doesn't mean it reads `2.3` characters.

Comment: I don't follow.. for an algorithm with complexity `O(log n)` where `n=10`, it does mean the algorithm inspects `log(10)` or `2.3` characters. It's an *example*. For `n=1000`, the `log n` is approx 6.9, so I don't see any constant of proportionality here. Could you clarify?

Comment: `O(log n)` is about the time it takes as n gets larger and larger, so an individual example for a specific value of `n` can never prove that it does or doesn't have a particular time complexity. If it could be proved that an algorithm takes exactly `Math.floor(1000000 * log(n))` steps, the time complexity would be `O(log n)` because you are allowed to just ignore large factors like `1000000`. So the fact that you can't read a string of length 10 by checking 2.3 characters isn't really relevant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments, so would the most efficient algorithm for this scenario be O (n log n) ?

Comment: @user3667111 No you can do it in `O(n)`. Use two `HashMap<Character, Integer>` to count occurrences, then check the maps are equal.

Comment: With the risk of @PaulBoddington's wrath (;-) Thanks for explanation - I know what you mean), `n log n` isn't necessarily faster: for the example `n = 10`, `2n = 20` but `n * log(n) = 23` (approx), and this only gets worse as `n` gets larger: for `n=1000`, `2n=2000` but `1000*log(n)=6907` (approx).

Comment: @PaulBoddington you're cheating ;-) You'd have to increment 2 maps in the loop, which is as many operations as two loops each incrementing 1 map (barring the overhead for not unrolling the loops), and then you'd have to iterate once more over the map to check equality. That'd be slower than the `O(2n)`. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Kenney There is no wrath. I thought it was a really good answer and I was trying to be constructive about how you could improve it. I was going to upvote if you'd made the edit.

Comment: @Kenney There would be 3 loops. One to populate the first map, one to populate the second, and a third to check the maps are equal. So the overall time complexity is `O(3n)`. This is the same as `O(n)` because `O` notation does not take constant proportions (here `3`) into account.

Comment: @Paul I'm just kidding - I really appreciate your feedback. I'd like to keep the example though as I find it can cut through misunderstanding and show hard numbers, but do away with the order, and reference the exact runtime. Do you have a suggestion?